# Как сравнить 2 Enum разных классов

Tags: c#, linq

Имеется два списка разных классов. Стоит задача заджоинить один в другой. У меня не получается сравнить данные два Enum из разных классов.

```
 var newManufacture = (from m in manufaturers
                                 join c in computers1 on m.Name equals c.MName
                                 select new { Name = c.MName, Model = m.Name, Employees = m.Employees }).ToList();
```

Если оставить как есть ругается что переменные разных типов. Как можно их сравнить? Я пробовал GetType(), GetHashCode() и все равно размер нового списка 0.

Comment: На сколько помнится, вы не сможете заджоинить два енума, т.к. енумы - это константы.

Comment: @ГеннадийП А можно сравнить не чистые Enum'ы, а например, как я в вопросе писал Hash или что то подобное?

Comment: Дайте конкретный пример. По идее, вам не должно такого хотеться. А если хочется, значит допущена ошибка при проектировании приложения. Вопрос в том, ехать дальше на костылях, или исправить ошибку проектирования. В принципе в обоих случаях надо понять, в чём задача заключается, и почему понадобились именно перечисления.

Comment: @aepot Слава Богу это лаба, не приложение. Делаешь 2 класса с заданными полями, потом делаешь списки обоих классов. И мучаешь их LINQ. Одно из заданий заджоинить один такой список в другой. Просто других полей одинаковых кроме Enum нет.

Comment: Может проще сделать поле в классе с List-ом, которое джоинь с чем угодно.

Comment: @ГеннадийП надо будет узнать у препода. Я тоже подумал, что так будет проще. Спасибо

Comment: Так перечисление надо объявлять вне класса как `public enum`, и в обоих классах использовать одно и то же перечисление. Вот и решение. Никогда не объявляйте перечисления внутри классов.

Comment: _Делаешь 2 класса с заданными полями, потом делаешь списки обоих классов._ - сделайте это и предоставьте нам код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно ли сравнивать? Конечно можно.

Можно сравнивать ассоциированніе значения энамов. Можно присвоить кастомные (например инты), а можно дефолтные.

---

Но как заметил aepot - явно что-то плохое намечается. И лучше разобраться как сделать правильно чем делать то, что задумал автор вопроса.

Comment: А если не присваивать, то что будет, куда вдруг инты денутся? Проверьте.

Comment: нету где, у меня под рукой сейчас только мак и винда будет не скоро под рукой.

Comment: [Эмм](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/mac/)....а винда тут при чем?

Comment: можно поставить, но не хочу) У меня здесь место не резиновое)) Эт у меня на виндовом компьютере место резиновое, а доступа к виндовому не будет еще минимум месяц =)

Comment: Ясно, отмаза всегда есть.

Comment: в общем и целом я на слово верю)

Comment: Ну тогда надо "нужно присвоить" убрать.